# How can I make a part of a formula to vary?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make just a part of the code change while the worksheet change, but it does not work. Changing from one worksheet to other is OK, but the changing integer do not work in the code. I create the J Integer to grow in one unit as the worksheet change. Therefore, the graph and the shapes are based on another Sheet (Dados) which has the data in different lines to provide the information to each worksheet.

```
Sub relatorio()
Dim ws As Worksheet, GI As Integer, GF As Integer, J As Integer
J = 0
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        J = J + 1
        If .Name = "Brasil" Then
            i = (8 * J) + 4   'the 8 is the amount of lines below I need to catch and the 4 is because the data starts on line 4. 
            GI = (13 * J) + 271
            Gf = (13 * J) + 283    
        End If
        If .Name <> "Dados" Then
            With .Shapes("TRI")
                .Formula = "=Dados!a2"
                .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
            End With
```

It does not work from the following step on.
Would you please help me to solve this problem?

```
        With .Shapes("PIT")
            .Formula = "=Dados!E(i)"
            .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
        End With
        With .ChartObjects("Gráfico 8")
            ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Dados!$e$(GI):$e$(GF)"
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Dados!$b$(GI):$c$(GF)"
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelTop)
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "#.##0,0"
        End with
    End if
Next
end sub
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail; what do you mean by 'It does not work from the following step on.' what are you expecting it to do, and what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the line that is causing the problem is .Formula `= "=Dados!E(i)" ,  is I intended to be a variable ? as it is written it is not.  I know you assign it in the previous sheet, but for this sheet it is not.

Perhaps try:  `.Formula = "=Dados!E(" & i & ")"`

Comment: @WilliamKratochwill glad to help, if this worked please mark it as the answer so no one else tries to solve it :D

Answer (score 0):

First off I would get the variable declarations in line with the scope of a modern worksheet. It may not matter now but it is a good practise to get into.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, GI As Long, GF As Long, J As Long
```

Next, the construction of cell ranges from string constants and numerical variables does not look correct. You are trying to create something like `=Dados!E99` not `=Dados!E(i)` when *i* has the value of *99*.

```
    With .Shapes("PIT")
        .Formula = "=Dados!E" & i
        ...
    End With
    With .ChartObjects("Gráfico 8")
        ...
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Dados!$e$" & GI & ":$e$" & GF
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Dados!$b$" & GI & ":$c$" & GF
        ...
    End with
```